# Why don't my Quote Marks work inside the CMD

Tags: c#

Im currently trying to run openVPN from a CMD that is programatically created.

Below is the code that I have created:

```
private void btnRunVpn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string openVpnDir = @"""C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin\openvpn.exe""";
        string myDir = @"""C:\Users\Jeremy\Desktop\OpenSource Rat\easyRDPClient\TutClient\bin\Debug\NewServerClient.ovpn""";
        string configCommand = " --config ";
        string command = openVpnDir + configCommand + myDir;
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", "/K " + command);

        MessageBox.Show(command);

    }
```

The message box displays the correct Command:

```
"C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin\openvpn.exe" --config "C:\Users\Jeremy\Desktop\OpenSource Rat\easyRDPClient\TutClient\bin\Debug\NewServerClient.ovpn"
```

However the command prompt is returning:

```
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

The command is deffinatly correct because the message box that displays the command is correct, also when i copy what is in the message box into the command prompt it works perfectly.

wondering if it is anything to do with the two strings created that both have @"""message""" to display the message correctly. Wondering if that is the issue.

I can't seem escape the double quotes properly because it is a directory. So Im forced to use the @"""test""" to display a command like this `"test"`

Wondering if anyone understands this a little more than I do.

Would be great help.

Thankyou in advance!

Comment: The issue looks like it is because you are using CMD.exe /K to run the command. This is most likely reading your arguments (which removes the quotes), and then running the command you specified without the quotes. You may be able to escape them twice to work around it. Is there a reason you are using "CMD.exe /K" instead of just changing the code to: System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(openVpnDir, configCommand + myDir);

Comment: @Wiz I kinda need the application to stay open once it has been ran so that is why I included the /K. Ill see how it works without it though.

Comment: @Wiz wow that actually worked thankyou! How do i stop the command prompt from closing when it's done with that method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this will do what you are hoping to accomplish. It should leave the command line open, and correct the issue where the quotes are removed.

In the sample below, I added quotes around the command variable in the Start command.

```
private void btnRunVpn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string openVpnDir = @"""C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin\openvpn.exe""";
    string myDir = @"""C:\Users\Jeremy\Desktop\OpenSource Rat\easyRDPClient\TutClient\bin\Debug\NewServerClient.ovpn""";
    string configCommand = " --config ";
    string command = openVpnDir + configCommand + myDir;
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", "/K " + "\"" + command + "\"");

    MessageBox.Show(command);

}
```

What I believe is happening is the CMD /K is expecting 1 argument. Since you are passing multiple, it is only looking at the first one (and removes the quotes when it does). This leaves it with:

```
C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin\openvpn.exe
```

It then cannot locate the application because of the space in the path.

By wrapping the entire command in quotes, it forces CMD to treat it as a single argument. It then removes the outer quotes and processes the desired command.

I tried it with Notepad in VB.NET, so hopefully I adjusted it correctly for your scenario.